# Sort the first level of a 2d array based on the element count of each row in a descending direction

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, count

I'm trying to sort a two dimensional array by the length of the inner arrays (descending).

This array:

```
[
    ['a'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['a', 'b'],
]
```

Desired result:

```
[
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['a'],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `usort` to sort by the `count()` of the elements.

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/plain");

$array = array(
    array(
        "item1" => "key1",
        "item2" => "key2",
    ),
    array(
        "item1" => "key1",
        "item2" => "key2",
        "item3" => "key3"
    ),
    array(
        "item1" => "key1",
    )
);

usort($array, function($el1, $el2) {
    if (count($el1) === count($el2)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return count($el1) < count($el2) ? 1 : -1;
});

print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Comparison function
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $ca = count($a);
    $cb = count($b);
    if($ca == $cb)
        return 0;
    return ($ca < $cb ) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Sort the array
uasort($array, 'cmp');
```

Answer (score 1):

Minimize the total required `count()` calls by creating a temporary sorting array for `array_multisort()` to sort the input array by.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kVZPH))

```
array_multisort(
    array_map('count', $array),
    SORT_DESC,
    $array
);
var_export($array);
```